# Dynamic Javascript variable names

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385084/javascript-dynamic-variables)

Can I have something like this is Jquery

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   var (eval(i+17)) = y;
   y++;
}
```

I need this because I want to have dynamic variable created on fly any should be able to asign values to it.

Comment: ....huh?  This question no sense.

Comment: Your code isn't making sense to us.  You're trying to do `var eval(17)= y;` which turns into `var 17 = y;`.  This doesn't make sense and isn't legal javascript.  Please clarify what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer here is to use arrays:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i + 17] = y;
    y++;
}
```

If you know your current context, you can create variables in it the same way. Say, for the global (`window`) scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window[i + 17] = y;
    y++;
}
```

But that means you're stomping all over your scope with random variable names. Keep them in one array instead.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't have to use arrays. You can use objects just as well.

```
var y = 0;
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    obj[i + 17] = y
    arr[i + 17] = y;
    y++;
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

The console output would look (expanded) like that:

```
Object
    17: 0
    18: 1
    19: 2
    20: 3
    21: 4
    22: 5
    23: 6
    24: 7
    25: 8
    26: 9
    __proto__: Object

    [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
undefined, undefined, undefined, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

JSFiddle to play with is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CHDqQ/).

The added benefits of using object are:

- your `obj` var should be smaller in size than your `arr` variable, since it won't have "unused indices"
- You could name your dynamic variable whatever you want, as opposed to array - where it has to be an integer.

The following would work for object and fail to add any variable to array:

```
var y = 0;
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    obj['my variable' + (i + 17)] = y
    arr['my variable' + (i + 17)] = y;
    y++;
}
```

The `arr` would look like that:

```
Object
    my variable17: 0
    my variable18: 1
    my variable19: 2
    my variable20: 3
    my variable21: 4
    my variable22: 5
    my variable23: 6
    my variable24: 7
    my variable25: 8
    my variable26: 9
    __proto__: Object
```

and `arr` would be empty: `[]`

Comment: +1 for objects, they would indeed be more correct to use for non-sequential or non-numerical keys.