# How to get variable value base on two variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I need some help with a javascript principle.
I have a variable where part of the variable name is "dynamic". Let me try to explain;

```
var name_city = "London";
var name_code = "500";
```

From the webpage I got an value named "type". This will be  "city" or "code".

(I just make it manualy here for the sake of this example)

```
var type = "city";
```

So with "city" as the value of type, I now want to alert "name_city". 
But I have no idea on how to do this with javascript.

Does anyone know?

In php I think it will be like this:

```
$type = "city";

$varname = 'name_'. $type;
echo ${$varname};
```

I appreciate any help or some clue in the right direction :-)

Comment: Try looking at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762502/dynamic-javascript-variable-names, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385084/javascript-dynamic-variables?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826154/can-i-create-dynamic-object-names-in-javascript?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you would need to store the data within an *object literal*, where you can access its keys dynamically. If you write those variables in the `global` / `window` object you can access them the same way.

```
// global scope
var name_city = "London";

var type = "city";

console.log( window[ "name_" + type ] );
```

---

This won't work if you aren't in the global scope (which actually, should not be the case at all). So you should store the data in a self-defined object

```
var data = {
    "name_city":  "London",
    "name_code":  "500"
};
```

and then do the same thing, just access via

```
console.log( data[ "name_" + type ] );
```

Comment: +1 You finished the scope issue before me so I've deleted mine above.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have several "parallel" variables all describing different aspects of the same entity, you'll almost always be better off using an object instead, i.e.

```
var name = {city: "London", code: 500};
```

You can then access the individual attributes by indexing with a variable, e.g. `name[type]` or by property name, e.g. `name.code`. A big advantage is that you can treat the object as a unit for purposes like passing it to a function rather than having to pass several different variables.