# How apply an alphabetical function on a var?

Tags: javascript

How i can sum up these var ?

```
var curb = $("#nav-b").position().top;
var curc = $("#nav-c").position().top;
var curd = $("#nav-d").position().top;
var cure = $("#nav-e").position().top;
var curf = $("#nav-f").position().top;
var curg = $("#nav-g").position().top;
var curi = $("#nav-i").position().top;
```

I have tried something using this:

```
var let = '';
var charCodeRange = {
    start: 66,
    end: 90
} // b to z
for (var cc = charCodeRange.start; cc <= charCodeRange.end; cc++) {
    let = String.fromCharCode(cc);
    'cur' + let = $("#nav-" + let).position().top;
}
```

Comment: Why not push all the values into an array and add them that way?

Comment: `let` is a keyword - don't use it as a variable name

Comment: use a class name instead and you can select all those elements in one call.

Comment: Assuming your problem is `cur + let = ...`, this is probably a duplicate of [Dynamic Javascript variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762502/dynamic-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using classnames? You can just put the class of "letter" on the ones you need. Here's a quick example.

```
var total = 0;

$('.letter').each(function(){
  total += $(this).position().top;
});
```

Comment: I use them in functions after:   if($("#nav-b").position().top < 20 && $("#nav-b").position().top > -20)
  {
   if(curb < $("#nav-b").position().top)
    changeNavIndicator("A");
   else
    changeNavIndicator("B");;
   curb = $("#nav-b").position().top;
  }