# Javascript Dynamic pointer allocation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering whether I can assign the pointer of a variable as something along the lines of

```
"image"+i+".src"
```

I've tried using eval, because that's the only suggestion I've found, but I'm being thrown a undefined variable error. Here's my code, if someone wouldn't mind taking a look:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            m = 0
            x = 0
            image=[  //Initializes the Array for Image URLs, Add object by adding the full URL in "" with , in between each entry
                "http://i.imgur.com/OaElB10.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/NTYiEB9.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/X1jreGc.jpg"]
            function ImgPreloadHandler()
            {                
                l = image.length
                for(t=0; t<l; t++)
                {
                    var image+t = new image()
                        image+t = image[t]
                }
            }
            ImgPreloadHandler()
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mv3sV8m.png" name="slide" width="796" height="600" />
        <script>
            function slideit()
            {            
                var step = 0
                var z = step
                if (!document.images)//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
                    return
                        document.images.slide.src=
                    if (step<x)
                        step++
                    else
                        step=1
                setTimeout("slideit()",2500)//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
            }
        slideit()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to generate a list of values, use an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - dynamic variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385084/javascript-dynamic-variables)

Comment: There are no pointers in JavaScript, and you cannot allocate memory manually. Also you cannot (should not) create dynamic variable names. Just use the `image` array that you already have!

Comment: For your actual problem, see [JavaScript Preloading Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images) - to preload an image, create an `image` html element (does not need to be in the document) and assign to the `src` attribute of it.

Comment: Don't use `<!-- ... //-->` unless you really, really must support Netscape 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a dynamic variable name. But there's plenty of other solutions.

Why not create an Object that contains your image values?

```
var images = {};

for(t=0; t<l; t++) {
  images[image + t] = image[t];
}


console.log(images);
> { 
    image0: "http://i.imgur.com/OaElB10.jpg",
    image1: "http://i.imgur.com/NTYiEB9.jpg",
    image2: "http://i.imgur.com/X1jreGc.jpg"
  }
```

By the way, don't use eval :)